# jobScheduler throttling specifications Android 11 (api 30)

Tags: android-source, android-jobscheduler, android-11

I'm developing an app which heavily relies on jobScheduler to perform multiple tasks in the background.
As of the next api version (android11, api 30), the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler) (and in the [developer preview](https://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes-all#jobscheduler_quotas)) states:

```
JobScheduler will throttle runaway applications. Calling schedule(android.app.job.JobInfo) and other such methods with very high frequency is indicative of an app bug and so, to make sure the system doesn't get overwhelmed, JobScheduler will begin to throttle apps that show buggy behavior, regardless of target SDK version.
```

But I couldn't find any specifications regarding what is 'normal' use of jobScheduler.

I tried looking for the source code, but couldn't find the android11 branch under the AOSP, and it's not mentioned under the list of [build-numbers](https://source.android.com/setup/start/build-numbers#source-code-tags-and-builds).

They DO offer an emulator version to perform tests, but I prefer knowing my boundaries (rather than performing battery of tests just to figure out what those numbers are).

I'd appreciate if anyone can point me to the feature specs or to the android11 source code.

Comment: "but couldn't find the android11 branch under the AOSP" -- source usually is not available until later, closer to the release date. You might consider filing a bug report to try to get them to improve the documentation for this.